# How do I get and display the album_art for a media player

Tags: java, android, database

I've spent ages searching for this and I'm now at the point where I see no alternative but to ask for help.
I'm trying to display album art within a media player I'm using. I have almost everything else fully functional including the other metadata, playing albums (vs. individual tracks) etc.
My code at the moment is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     System.gc();

     View cellLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.albumbrowsercell, null);
     ImageView album_art = (ImageView) cellLayout.findViewById(R.id.albums_album_cover);
     TextView album_title = (TextView) cellLayout.findViewById(R.id.albums_album_title);
     TextView artist_title = (TextView) cellLayout.findViewById(R.id.albums_artist_title);

     String albumName;
     String artistName;
     int albumID;

     album_column_index = albumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);
     albumCursor.moveToPosition(position);
     albumID = albumCursor.getInt(album_column_index);
     Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
     Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumID);
     album_art.setImageURI(uri);
     //code to do set text above etc.

return cellLayout;
```

Logcat is giving errors similar to this:
I/System.out(12781): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: album_art/224
Hence the problem seems to be with the appendedID. I don't know how else to call it though (I even resorted to trying random numbers to see if I could hit on one).

It's possible that I'm making a fundamental mistake. Most of my time spend so far has been due to learning how to work with the content providers etc and I'm still not even 50% sure about them (never done Databases or Android before).

Also, is it just be me or is the Android documentation, at least regarding this topic, pretty rubbish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALBUM_ART is a column name, not a content URI. You need to query the album and get the column with the name ALBUM_ART. This will presumably give you a URI to the ImageStore (dunno, haven't tried it myself).

Btw, there is [an open bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1630) about the ABLUM_ART column, but I would suggest you try it first - grab the ALBUM_ART column and see what's in there.

Sample code (note that this is off the top of my head, so it could be wrong):

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
              ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                  MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, albumId),
              new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART },
              null,
              null,
              null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String albumArtUri = cursor.getString(0);
}

cursor.close();
```

Again, no guarantees this works, I've never used the media store, and I wrote this code without being able to test it.

Comment: So I query it like so?  
String[] columnValues = {
              MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
            };
         albumArtCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columnValues, null, null, null);

Comment: I'll add an example. Also, I wouldn't use a managedQuery since you can close the cursor immediately again.

Comment: Great to hear!! Good luck with your app!

Comment: Hey listen, after getting the URI what should be done????if i have to store it as a bitmap??

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me..

```
Cursor cursorAlbum = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=" + album_id, null, null);

        if(cursorAlbum != null  && cursorAlbum.moveToFirst()){

            String uri = cursorAlbum.getString(cursorAlbum.getColumnIndex("album_art"));
            cursorAlbum.close();
            if(uri != null ) 
                {
                    //Log.i("albumUri", uri);
                    wrapper.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
                }
            }
```